# Is there a scalaTest method or attribute that can be used to run ONLY once just after all tests in all suites

Tags: scala, automated-tests, scalatest

I have a group of test suites that will grow too, and I need to run a testcleanup task that should run only once just after all the tests have finished execution and before the test process exits. This is similar to .NET AssebmlyCleanup, but I couldn't find something equivalent in the Scala/Scalatest world without having to do custom code, is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've been thinking how to approach this and one way to do this is to override a bit `test` and `testOnly` in our `build.sbt`.
So suppose we have under `src/test/scala` following two suites:

```
class Suite1 extends FlatSpec{
  "Test1 in Suite1" should "succeed" in{
    succeed
  }
}
```

and

```
class Suite2 extends FlatSpec{
  "Test1 in Suite2" should "succeed" in{
    succeed
  }
}
```

Now let's add under the `/project/` folder a `CleanUp.scala` object where our cleanup will live:

```
object CleanUp{
  def cleanUp:Unit = println("Cleaning up after all suites are completed.")
}
```

That's a minimal example, actually you may have there whatever complex cleanup you need.
Now in our `build.sbt` let's add following:

```
(test in Test) := {
  val testsResult = (test in Test).value
  CleanUp.cleanUp
  testsResult
}

(testOnly in Test) := {
  (testOnly in Test).evaluated
  CleanUp.cleanUp
}
```

This overrides the default behavior of the `test` and `testOnly` tasks so the cleanup will be applied after all suites (or all specified by the user suites) are executed.

For example, here is my sbt console check of the new `testOnly`:

```
[IJ]sbt:AfterAllTests> testOnly Suite1
[info] Suite1:
[info] Test1 in Suite1
[info] - should succeed
[info] Run completed in 150 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
Cleaning up after all suites are completed.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 2, 2017 12:19:48 AM
[IJ]sbt:AfterAllTests>
```

And here is check of new `test`:

```
[IJ]sbt:AfterAllTests> test
[info] Suite2:
[info] Test1 in Suite2
[info] - should succeed
[info] Suite1:
[info] Test1 in Suite1
[info] - should succeed
[info] Run completed in 164 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
Cleaning up after all suites are completed.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Dec 2, 2017 12:28:25 AM
[IJ]sbt:AfterAllTests>
```

As you can see cleanup gets invoked.
Hope this helps.